# Socket чтение buffer

Tags: c++, linux

Здравствуйте!
Я в c++ новичок и у меня возникла проблема, не знаю как прочитать ответ из буфера socket сервера

Мой сайт отправляет данные

```
int opcode 
int key_len 
string key 
string command или char command
```

Как мне это прочитать? 
Сейчас я делаю с помощью memcpy но когда пытаюсь достать string он выдает его с лишним символом в конце

Не могли бы вы мне помочь и дать информацию по этому вопросу? как правильно все это организовать.

```
int countByte = recv(client->get_socket(), bufferT, 2048, 0);
        int opcode;
        memcpy(&opcode, bufferT + p, 4);
        p += 4;
        int keyLen;
        memcpy(&keyLen, bufferT + p, 4);
        p += 4;
        char server_key[keyLen];
        memcpy(&server_key, bufferT + p, keyLen);
        p += keyLen;
```

Comment: А как вы отправляете? есть у меня нехорошее подозрение, что вы отправку `string key` выполняете как `send(&key,sizeof(key)` или что-то вроде того...

Comment: key я сравниваю который пришел с сайта с тем, что на сервере. типа защита можно так сказать. А на сайте отправляю так pack('i', strlen($key)).$key . Первый ключ получает нормально а далее с символом в конце добавляется, например key@ или может + или еще какой-то

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Можно добавить пару вспомогательных функций (на будущее):

```
template <class T> 
T read_pod(const char*& buffer) {
    static_assert(std::is_pod<T>::value, "only pod types are allowed here");
    T value{};
    std::memcpy(reinterpret_cast<char*>(&value), buffer, sizeof(T));
    buffer += sizeof(T);
    return value;
};

std::string read_string(const char*& buffer, size_t length) {
    std::string value;
    value.resize(length);
    std::memcpy(&value[0], buffer, length);
    buffer += length;
    return value;
};
```

[Полный код с примером использования](https://wandbox.org/permlink/EvHRIeIDbaIoLkhm)

Нюансы:

- Убедитесь, что используете типы нужного размера. Если ключ отправляется в виде 4х байт, то и принимайте не в какой-то `int`, а конкретный `uint32_t`.
- Убедитесь, что на отправляющей и принимающей стороне совпадает endianness - порядок байт.
- Не используйте `char arr[non_const_var]` - это не является стандартом языка. Но если очень хочется, замените на `char server_key[keyLen + 1]{};` и всё заработает.